# How to create azure datafactory pipeline?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Could anyone suggest, How to create pipeline for specific tables from azure synapse to azure blob storage.

Example:I have 10 tables like 
table1,
table2,
table3,
...,
...,
I want to fetch only table1, table5, table 7,table 8,table 9, table 10 and need to load into azure blob stoarge.

My synapse and blob both in azure cloud.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I suggest .

1. Create a variable of type array and load the table names.
2. Use a for each activity
3. Inside the foreach activity use a copy activity , add the source as the synapse and you will have to use parameterized dataset to pass the table name . The sink should be blob .

This article does the reverse , but it will be give you some idea of the logic . 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53367.azure-data-factory-v2-copy-content-of-multiple-blob-to-different-sql-tables.aspx

Let me know how it goes .